# Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}(K_1\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})/K_1)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups, hecke-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a non-Archimedean local field. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers, and let $\frak{m}$ be its maximal ideal Let $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ be the group of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}$ such that their inverse also has coefficients in $\mathcal{O}$.

Let $K_1\subset \GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ be the subgroup of matrices defined by
$$K_1:=\{X\in \GL_n(\mathcal{O})\mid X\equiv I_n \bmod \frak{m}\}.$$

**What is known about the structure the Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}(K_1\backslash \GL_n(\mathbb{F})/K_1)$ of locally constant and compactly supported  functions on $\GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ invariant with respect to left and right translations by $K_1$ and equipped with usual convolution?**

Comment: I think the structure of this Hecke algebra is known, cf. Roger Howe "Harish-Chandra homomorphisms for p-adic groups" CBMS regional conference series in maathematics, vol. 59, 1985.